# Biblatex problem with full stop/question mark/ellipsis at the end of title influencing later bib macros

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, biber, biblatex-dw

I have a problem with `biblatex-dw` when there are titles ending with a full stop, ellipsis symbol or question mark. They are interpreted as end of a sentence and influence later bib macros.

In the MWE the `\textelp{}` (which is required here) of the entry ABC has the effect that the

> Trans. by

is written with an uppercase 'T' instead of the desired behaviour of entry ABC2 with output

> , trans. b

So I'm looking for a way to somehow hide the full stop/question mark/ellipses from the bib macro.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=footnote-dw]{biblatex}
\usepackage[]{csquotes}

\begin{filecontents*}{MWE.bib}
@BOOK{ABC,
    author = {Cornelisse, J. W. and Schoeyer, H. Ferry R. and Wakker, Karel F.},
        translator  = {Smith, John}, 
    title = {Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics \textelp{}},
    year = {1979},
    publisher = {Pitman},
}

@BOOK{ABC2,
    author = {Cornelisse, J. W. and Schoeyer, H. Ferry R. and Wakker, Karel F.},
        translator  = {Smith, John}, 
    title = {Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics},
    year = {1979},
    publisher = {Pitman},
}
\end{filecontents*}


\bibliography{MWE.bib}

\begin{document}
     Not the desired output\autocite[][]{ABC}.
    Desired output\autocite[][]{ABC2}.
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently, the `\textelp{}` makes `biblatex`'s punctuation tracker think that the title ends in a sentence-ending full stop. `biblatex` then suppresses the unwanted double punctuation of a sentence-ending full stop and a comma. You can tell `biblatex` that the `\textelp{}` is not a sentence-ending full stop with `\isdot`.

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=footnote-dw]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{ABC,
  author     = {Cornelisse, J. W. and Schoeyer, H. Ferry R. and Wakker, Karel F.}  ,
  translator = {Smith, John}, 
  title      = {Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics \textelp{}\isdot},
  year       = {1979},
  publisher  = {Pitman},
}
@book{ABC2,
  author     = {Cornelisse, J. W. and Schoeyer, H. Ferry R. and Wakker, Karel F.},
  translator = {Smith, John}, 
  title      = {Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics},
  year       = {1979},
  publisher  = {Pitman},
}
\end{filecontents*}

\bibliography{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
  Not the desired output\autocite[][]{ABC}.
  Desired output\autocite[][]{ABC2}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Foonote 1 "J. W. Cornelisse/H. Ferry R. Schoeyer/Karel F. Wakker: Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics [...], trans. by John Smith, 1979."//Footnote 2 "Idem: Rocket Propulsion and Spaceflight Dynamics, trans. by John Smith, 1979."]

Comment: moewe, Would it be viable to set something in `\DeclareCapitalPunctuation`?

Comment: @gusbrs Could be tricky, the default is `DeclareCapitalPunctuation{.!?}`, which does not include the ellipsis explicitly. But in standard LaTeX `\textellipsis` is built up from `.` (cf. https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/258591/35864), so one can't simply do something for `.` but not for `\textellipsis`. Cf. also https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/514 and in particular https://github.com/moewew/biblatex/commit/5de1c77d639e4fdea5506bfdb3c90ec63be8c35c.

Comment: @gusbrs To see a different outcome, compile the MWE from the OP with `\usepackage[LY1]{fontenc}`. `LY1` has a dedicated ellipsis character.

Comment: @moewe Mmh, even trickier than I thought. Thanks for the explanation.